# Grails create request to match a different action

Tags: grails

When a user hits a send email url then I want to render a view for the email.

However the html needs some apache substitutions applied to it. these can change without notice and are different for each environment.

For instance...

```
imagedomain.placeholder/dishwasher.png
```

would be switched for the following

```
stage.myimagecdn.com/dishwasher.png
```

or

```
actual.myimagecdn.com/dishwasher.png
```

So, I have a view that renders the email template and two actions:

email

and

renderEmail

I can send identical POST body, and headers to both actions.

The email action checks that everything is ok and then calls send in the mailService

```
def send(EmailCommand cmd) {
    // This is the line that I need help with
    def mailBody = render(controller: "configurator", action: "emailRender", cmd: cmd)
    sendMail {
        to cmd.to
        from "getintouch@mydomain.com"
        subject "My Subject Line"
        body mailBody
    }
}
```

Is there a groovy way to hit the controller?

Comment: maybe you just need to render a template and not call a controller. Calling a controller from service is the wrong way of doing things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755341/dry-layouts-for-grails-emails/37764340#37764340

Comment: Thanks Vahid, yeah, I think we're going to amend the image url domains as they come in from an API.  The apache mod_substitute stuff causes more problems than it solves for us I think

Comment: A little confused, don't think the question accurately illustrates the issue at hand. Whether you render template or do as you are doing by calling controller. In the gsp : <%@ page import="grails.util.Environment" %> 
<g:if test="${Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION}">   Do something - you can define urls based in the controller same way too but if it is images on the gsp then above should work ? http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-test-in-a-GSP-if-not-in-an-environment-td1384589.html

Comment: Are you familiar with the apache mod_substitute module vahid?

Comment: I see you mentioned apache substituion, think question is possibly misleading for those are not specifically aware of your actual setup / or what it is your trying to achieve. If you are emailing a page and this substitution is attempting to set the url this way. The above environment may also work and is within grails. if it is this then personally I prefer to include the images like described in first post. Having users point back to end images - depending on traffic can itself become a bottleneck

Comment: Just for the emails it's a problem as the user doesn't access the html by the apache server.  For instance in gmail or outlook.